# Table of integrals involving modified Bessel function of the second kind

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions, fourier-analysis

I need to compute integrals of the following form as accurately as possible (possibly with extended precision):

$$
I_{nl}(\omega)=\int_0^{1/2}\left(1-x^2\right)^{1/4} \sin (2 \pi  l x)\; \sin (2 \pi  n x) 
\;K_{i \omega }\left(2 n \pi \sqrt{1-x^2}\right){\rm d}x\,,
$$
where $(n,l)\in\mathbb{N}^2$, $\omega>0$ and the function $K_\alpha(z)$ is a modified Bessel function of the second kind. In the application I have in mind, I need to evaluate the above for $1\leq l\leq 50$, $1\leq n\leq 50$ and for several values of $\omega\in(0,200)$. I think that there must be a way to compute this by resorting to FFT, which would obviously be great. Any thoughts?

I have tried the following

```
nmax=50;
$MinPrecision=200;
N1=4000;
om = 200;
n = nmax;
f[x_] := 4 Sin[2 \[Pi] n x] (1 - x^2)^(1/4)BesselK[I om, 2 \[Pi] n Sqrt[1 - x^2]]
xg = 1/2 N[Range[N1 - 1], $MinPrecision]/N1;
fg = ParallelMap[f, xg];
coef = Chop[1/4 FourierDST[fg, 1], 10^-$MinPrecision]
```

with `coef` being the integrals I want to compute. The above example I am taking $n=50$ and $\omega =200$. `coef` is giving the list of integrals $I_{50\,l}(200)$ for $l=1,\ldots,50$.

Comment: What problem are you having with `NIntegrate`?

Comment: These integrals must be determined to a very good precision - say the first 200 digits or so. For this type of precision,```NIntegrate``` becomes very slow when $n,l\sim 50$ and $\omega \sim 200$. I have found a way to compute this that resorts to MM in-built function ```FourierDST```. However, I am not sure if it can be improved.

Comment: @user12588, please include the relevant Mathematica code in the question (ie. type your integrand, and show your usage of `FourierDST`).

Comment: @Domen, I have uploaded my try.

Comment: So you are approximating the continuous function as a discrete list of values? If you do that, can you really get 200 digits of precision with only 4000 points? Have you compared that approach with NIntegrate for small values of $n$, $l$, and $\omega$ to confirm it works there?